# How to automatically import video from YouTube?

Tags: joomla-3.x, content, rss

I just installed Joomla 3.0 and I'm not great at it. Here's what I'm looking for though. I give Joomla my YouTube channel's url or the url of it's RSS feed. When I do it checks this feed at a set interval constantly and forever in the future. If during one of these checks, it sees I have uploaded a new video it automattically updates so that the video is listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually recommend using something like Youtube Gallery. You can fully customize the output (though not into pages):

http://www.joomlaboat.com/youtube-gallery

Here's an example of the type of page you can make with it:

http://globalawakening.com/testimonies/video

Any time there's an update to the channel, it gets loaded into the site automatically.

Comment: Well this looks perfect! Now people don't have to leave my website!

Comment: Yep! We paid someone to write a custom module that does this for 3 videos on our front page...and THEN I discovered this gallery module. It's pretty slick.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the News Feed manager. Just go to the backend, load your youtube's rss url in the news feed manager, then create a menu item pointing to it.

Comment: How would I make each link have it's own page?

Comment: By convention rss feeds point to the original article, so you display them on your site, but by clicking you go to the site that originated the feed; to do anything different you might need to code.

Comment: My website is much more user friendly than I imagined.